# How to handle the table or csv file column that contains newLine character and manipulate in pyspark dataFrame having hdfs file system

Tags: python, database, dataframe, pyspark, hdfs

How to handle the column of either table/csv file which contains newline character in pyspark df in with hdfs file system.

I actually need to do manipulation on column data where having newline char which is not able to achieve with below mentioned step .

Challenge facing is tuple data with newline char is making new record and not able to parse it and manipulate on that in df

```
>>> df=spark.read.csv("hdfs://cluster-04d4-m/user/veerayyakumar_g/Cleansdata_Input_Test.csv", header = True, inferSchema = True).show()
+--------------------+----------+--------------------+---------------+-------------+---------+
|                item|item_group|     item_group_desc|item_group_qlty|product_group|   run_dt|
+--------------------+----------+--------------------+---------------+-------------+---------+
|            I1229422|        G1|"<?xml version=""...|           null|         null|     null|
|      <Instructions>|      null|                null|           null|         null|     null|
|    <Instruction ...|      null|                null|           null|         null|     null|
|        Instructi...|      null|                null|           null|         null|     null|
|     </Instructions>|      null|                null|           null|         null|     null|
| ,,P130872,4/22/2019|      null|                null|           null|         null|     null|

>>> df=spark.read.csv("hdfs://cluster-04d4-m/user/veerayyakumar_g/Cleansdata_Input_Test.csv", header = True, inferSchema = True).show()

tried manipluate using lambda function but it's not working 

>>> newdf["item_group_desc"]=df["item_group_desc"].apply(lambda x: x.replace("\n",""))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '__getitem__'


Tried with column funtion still not able to achive that my scenario where i wanted to bring the tuple data in single line in the column "item_group_desc"
>>> newdf=df["item_group_desc"].withColumn('item_group_desc',regexp_replace('item_group_desc','[\\n]',''))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

Need the column `item_group_desc` data in single line after removing the `newLine` char in it in `pyspark` of `hdfs` file system.

Comment: please format your code and data properly